# Unable to connect to Visual Studio's Localhost Web Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, localhost

Until yesterday everything was normal but today i try to lauch my application using Ctrl+F5 and i get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to Visual Studio's Localhost Web Server
```

I have tried

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

and

```
iisreset
```

but nothing works.

Any ideas??

Environment:
Windows XP
Visual Studio 2005

Comment: I do hope you didn't actually do the aspnet_regiis *before* iisreset! aspnet_regiis is a pretty brutal thing to do as a frst step.

Comment: Actually i did it!, but it didn't do anything anyway.

Comment: Changing the port fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found some answer but it didn't solved the problem.

Since I was using the Visual Studio Web Server and i was having problems I configured my web application project to use IIS instead and it worked.

But if i change it back to VS Web Server it still have the problem.
At least I can keep on working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your firewall. It may be blocking.

Check [this link which has some other possible reasons](http://forums.asp.net/t/905409.aspx).